# Recovering Files

Tags: dual-boot, files, data-recovery

Recently, I got a virus on my computer. I took it to an IT guy, and he had to backup all my files, factory reset the computer, and then put them back on again. Due to issues with windows authentication(He booted my computer from a windows 10 disc), I had to system restore to when he had not yet put all my files back on the computer. I installed Ubuntu, and I could see all of my Windows files again. Why? And how do i make sure that I don't lost any of those files?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run `sudo blkid` command. If it says just one line with `TYPE=ext4` it means you only have Ubuntu. If you have more than one lines, especially if it says `TYPE=ntfs` , you probably have installed Ubuntu together with Windows on your machine, so there is two OS on your disk now. Which is good ! You can still have your files *and* use them in virus-free way with Ubuntu. Windows viruses don't work in Ubuntu. Unless you have `Wine`,but that's whole lot of different story

Comment: I can't see the supposedly deleted files in windows, but I can see them on Ubuntu. Why? (also, i'm booting Ubuntu from a DVD)

Comment: OK . . . So you are booting from Live DVD  and try to access hard drive. Right ? What about the files themselves ? Could the files simply be hidden (you could boot your windows 7 and enable showing hidden files ) ? A file is a file , so it's not related to Ubuntu or Windows. If something is present on hard drive, then it's there regardless of the OS, but it may be that in Windows you have different settings, which dont apply in Ubuntu

Comment: i'll see if I can unhide the files. Maybe it's a windows 10 problem? Would you happen to know anything about that?

Comment: @patrickhuie19 I have not used Win10 , so wouldn't known about that, and like i said it shouldn't be an OS issue